# Sharing files through Chaton

Tags: android

My Application Need Share files On Chaton. I have Studied About Samsung Chaton Library.

I found that using this library, third party applications can send text and In Library They didn't write anything About sending files for third party Application. So Any one can Help me send Files for third Party Application ?

Comment: Check this [link](http://developer.samsung.com/chaton-api/resource). In this there is library using this library you can share file for third party app.